# Smarty 2 regex replace, string + any number

Tags: regex, smarty

I'm trying to do a regex replace (http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl) using smarty but I'm unsure of the correct regex syntax.

What im trying to achieve is turning:

- i-am-something-specific-thing-1
- i-am-something-specific-thing-2
- i-am-something-specific-thing-3
- i-am-something-specific-thing-4

into `i-am-something`

Any pointers and explanations as how the regex syntax would look like for this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with smarty, but it looks like you want something like this:

```
{$someVariable|regex_replace:"/-specific-thing-\d+$/":""}
```

This should remove `-specific-thing-` followed by any digit, when it appears at the end of a the string.

**Update** To replace that section of the string in a file name, use:

```
{$someVariable|regex_replace:"/-specific-thing-\d+\.html$/":".html"}
```

or this, which will work for any extension:

```
{$someVariable|regex_replace:"/-specific-thing-\d+(\.\w+)$/":"\\1"}
```

Comment: Psssst, you forgot `specific` :)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer; I've tried it but it doesn't seem to be working- would it make a different if what I'm replacing is in fact i-am-something-specific-thing-1.html to be i-am-something.html?

Comment: Excellent - thanks a bunch! I really must learn regex better - do you know of any good resources?

Comment: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) or the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) are good places to start.